# How to design for mockability when there is a dependency?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I have a method inside which it calls the .NET XDocument.Load() method to load the xml data from a url. I'd like to make my class unit testable.

So how to make that call mockable/unit testable?

```
private void ProcessData(string url)
{
            // todo: make this mockable
            var xDocument = XDocument.Load(url);
            // the rest of the code
}
```

One solution I've used is to inject an xmlUrlLoader into the clas like below:

```
private readonly Func<string, XDocument> _xmlUrlLoader;

public MyConstructor(Func<string,XDocument> xmlUrlLoader)
{
    _xmlUrlLoader = xmlUrlLoader;
}
private void ProcessData(string url)
{
            // todo: make this mockable
            var xDocument = this._xmlUrlLoader(url);
            // the rest of the code
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: I'd move the responsibility for the url loading one level up. So there is one function that takes the data as string or `XDocument` and processes it, and then a thin wrapper over it that downloads the data and passes it to the processing function. No mocking needed.

Comment: If i where you, i simply pass xDocument to this method.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I can't pass xDocument to it; I don't want to call xDocument.Load, that should be mocked/isolated.

Comment: `XDocument.Load` doesn't take urls, it only takes filenames. So how does your code work at all?

Comment: @CodesInChaos nope, it accepts a Uri (either local or external); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb343181.aspx that's the easiest way to load an Xml file over the web :)

Comment: The call to `XDocument.Load` is already mockable, and therefore the class already is unit testable. You can use a "proper" mocking tool such as JustMock or TypeMock Isolator to easily write the unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that injecting a loader is the correct approach I'm not sure why it would be of type Func

I would expect an interface along the lines of

```
public interface IXmlDocumentLoader
{
    XDocument LoadDocument(string url);
}
```

and then your code would look like

```
private readonly IXmlDocumentLoader _xmlUrlLoader;

public MyConstructor(IXmlDocumentLoader xmlUrlLoader)
{
    _xmlUrlLoader = xmlUrlLoader;
}

private void ProcessData(string url)
{
            var xDocument = this._xmlUrlLoader(url);
            // the rest of the code
}
```

But I think that for reasons of separation of concerns the document loader should definitely be in its own class.

Comment: This looks to be a valid simple approach of injecting a dependency. The downside is that I'd have to create a wrapper that will be part of production code but won't be unit testable.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer separating logic from accessing resources. In your case I'd pass the document to the processing function:

```
void ProcessData(XDocument xDocument);
```

You can test that function without mocking anything. Then if you want you can add a thin wrapper on top that does the loading.

```
void ProcessUrl(string url);
{
    var xDocument = XDocument.Load(url);
    ProcessData(xDocument);
}
```

You can use mocking to unit test the wrapper, but personally I don't see much gain in that. I prefer to exercise those wrappers only as part of integration tests.

Comment: I understand your point on separating the logic from accessing resourcing which is a valid point for readability improvement (arguably) but the above wouldn't solve the issue I raised, how would you mock it? creating an interface and a wrapper?

Comment: @TheLight I'd mainly test the version taking an `XDocument` without mocking anything. I can't say how or if I'd test the wrapper without context. Possibly with an `IFileSystem` interface, and possibly only with integration tests. | What you mock and how you test is a stylistic issue, and I prefer mocking as little as possible. Other people have different preferences.

Comment: I meant the wrapper that runs XDocument.Load(). I'd consider ProcessUrl() method a unit of test although it calls another method so that's why I need to mock. Units of tests don't always have to be one property or one single method. A collection of methods and even classes can be tested and they'd be unit tests still. If I'd be testing the integration of my codse with other external resources/systems (files, database, other web services), then I'd refer to them as integration tests. Otherwise, it's all unit tests.